# How to get all events from Firebase database in Alamkanak Android-Week-View library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add events dynamically from Firebase , but I'm not able to display any events, I am using [Alamkanak Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View) , I stuck with problem and try many ways because **onMonthChange** called before executing firebase, please help guys.

```
    private void RetriveAllAppointment(ArrayList<String> id_list) {
        mrefDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Appointments").child("Active");
        mrefDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     times_list = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                   appointmantdate = snapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
 selectedVenueName = snapshot.child("venueName").getValue().toString();
                                    if (snapshot.hasChild("times")) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot timesnapshot 

    :snapshot.child("times").getChildren()) {
    String time = timesnapshot.getValue().toString();
    times_list.add(time);}
                                        CreateEvent(year, month);}
```

create event from data that come from firebase

```
public void CreateEvent(int year, int month) {
        String[] separated = appointmantdate.split("-");
        int year_ = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);
        int month_ = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(separated[2]);
        for (int a = 0; a < times_list.size(); a++) {

            String[] timeSplit = times_list.get(a).split(":");
            int time_hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]);
            int time_minute = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]);

            Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time_hour);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_minute);
            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, month_ - 1);
            startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year_);
            Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();

            String[] endtimeSplit = times_list.get(times_list.size() - 1).split(":");
            int endtime_hour = Integer.parseInt(endtimeSplit[0]);
            int endtime_minute = Integer.parseInt(endtimeSplit[1]);
            endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, endtime_hour);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endtime_minute);
            endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
            event = new WeekViewEvent(1, selectedVenueName, startTime, endTime);
            event.setColor(getActivity(). getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_03));
            events.add(event);}
```

onMonthChange method

```
@Override
public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
    List<WeekViewEvent> lastone = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
    
    if (appointmantdate != null && times_list != null) {
      lastone = CreateEvent(newYear, newMonth);
        events.addAll(lastone);
    }
    ArrayList<WeekViewEvent> matchedEvents = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
    for (WeekViewEvent event : events) {
        if (eventMatches(event, newYear, newMonth)) {
            matchedEvents.add(event);
        }
     return matchedEvents;
```